# Overhang parameter of rowcolor changes overhang of each cell, not just the row

Tags: tables, booktabs, colortbl

I want to highlight a few rows in a table, and used `\rowcolor` as per the first table. Well, this results in the row coloring being wider than I desire, so I thought the simple fix would be to adjust the overhang of the row via the optional parameter

```
\rowcolor{cyan!20}[1pt]
```

But, this yields the result shown in the second table. The overhang was applied to each cell -- I just want to control the overhang of the entire row, not each cell.  That is, I want a solid colored row, but with the overhang adjusted on the left and the right of the row.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{clc}
$n$ & Text & $f(n)$ \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\rowcolor{cyan!20}
1   & abc    & 2      \\
2   & abc    & 1      \\ \rowcolor{cyan!20}
7   & abc    & 3      \\
8   & abc    & 2      \\
9   & abc    & 1      \\
10  & abc    & 2      \\
11  & abc    & 2      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{clc}
$n$ & Text & $f(n)$ \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\rowcolor{cyan!20}[1pt]%  <---- only change from above is the "[0pt]"
1   & abc    & 2      \\
2   & abc    & 1      \\ \rowcolor{cyan!20}
7   & abc    & 3      \\
8   & abc    & 2      \\
9   & abc    & 1      \\
10  & abc    & 2      \\
11  & abc    & 2      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a bit rubbish isn't it: who designed that interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\rowcolor` is implemented as "do this column colour in every cell of the row" which isn't what you want for the overhang, so:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{clc}
$n$ & Text & $f(n)$ \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\rowcolor{cyan!20}
1   & abc    & 2      \\
2   & abc    & 1      \\ \rowcolor{cyan!20}
7   & abc    & 3      \\
8   & abc    & 2      \\
9   & abc    & 1      \\
10  & abc    & 2      \\
11  & abc    & 2      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{clc}
$n$ & Text & $f(n)$ \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\rowcolor{cyan!20}
\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{cyan!20}[1pt][\tabcolsep]}c}{1}
   & abc    &
\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{cyan!20}[\tabcolsep][1pt]}c}{2}
     \\
2   & abc    & 1      \\ \rowcolor{cyan!20}
7   & abc    & 3      \\
8   & abc    & 2      \\
9   & abc    & 1      \\
10  & abc    & 2      \\
11  & abc    & 2      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very interesting that the choice of color specified for `\columncolor` in the `\multicolumn` does not matter!!